# How write mysql sub query in cakephp2.4

Tags: mysql, cakephp, subquery, cakephp-2.0

I am developing a chat script in cakephp2.4 and in that i am facing some complex sub query issues, basic join query and other conditions are easy to work, when it comes with complex sub quires for same table like following one is tough for me.

working MySQL query, which render perfect data for me

```
SELECT * FROM chat WHERE `poster_id` IN (
    SELECT `poster_id` FROM chat 
    WHERE `poster_id` = 2771 or `poster_id` = 2787 AND `enqNo` = 'OW-ENQ-kar217-343')
```

looking for cakephp sub query for the above query.

Comment: It's best to avoid asking "_can you do that for me_" questions, you'll get better help if you explain the specific problem that you have with writing the code.

Comment: Make sure that you've checked **https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries**

Comment: thanks ndm i am new to the stack overflow. definitely i will correct it in the future questions